# Spring Data JPA - one to one mapping bidirectional

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping

I have a table called symbols and symbol history,

```
 Symbols
    symbols(Pk)
    
 SymbolsHistorical
    id
    symbols
    Forign key name - symbols_fk (FK)
```

I created my HibernateMapping and in my DTO classes,

In SymbolsHistorical,

```
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "symbols_fk"))
private Symbols symbol;
```

I did in Symbols class,

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "symbol")
private SymbolsHistorical symbolsHistorical;
```

Whenever I need to read symbols, I need its symbolsHistorical as well,

Iam using findBySymbol method to get symbolsData. Whenever I do the above mapping, am getting,
Unknown column 'symbols0_.symbols_historical_id' in 'field list'

What am doing wrong?

Update:

```
Error 
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:728)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:755)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:178)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:728)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:755)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:178)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:728)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:755)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:178)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:728)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:755)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:178)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:728)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:755)

[2m2021-07-05 15:31:29.458[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m76390[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-1][0;39m [36ms.e.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$StaticView[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Cannot render error page for request [/symbols/A] and exception [] as the response has already been committed. As a result, the response may have the wrong status code.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taken from your tables the foreign key name is symbols.

So the mapping must be in `Symbols` class:

```
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name="symbols")
private Symbols symbol;
```

As you are using JSON serialization you will get a StackOverflowError because of the bi-directional mapping.

So you have to add an annotation to the `Symbol` or `SymbolsHistorical` class (depending on what you want to serialize) to break the loop.

For example

```
@JsonBackReference // this property will not be serialized
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "symbol")
private SymbolsHistorical symbolsHistorical;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Updated the question. symbols is foreign key column name and foreign key name is symbols_fk. I assumed its self explanatory.

Comment: Did you try my answer?

Comment: I added this in SymbolHistorical class. And this will fetch symbols while reading symbolsHistorical. I added 
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "symbol")
private SymbolsHistorical symbolsHistorical;
in Symbols, but am getting infinite looping, as symbols is returning symbolsHistorical and symbolsHistorical is returning symbols.

Comment: Are you using Lombok? Or what is creating the infinite loop?

Comment: Yes am using Lombok. Will it create problems? I have also updated the error meesage am getting.

Comment: I removed Lombok in those classes and it worked the same way how it was working before.

Comment: I've updated my answer with the information how to break the loop on Json serialization

Comment: For now, i don't have scenario to get both bidirectional contents. If there are such scenario's. Any solution for that?

Comment: No this will always produce a loop. JSON data is a tree not a graph